# C# Razor Syntax - html.displayfor displaying as text, not html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, razor

My models:

```
    public class htmlDump {
        public string html { get; set; }
    }

    public string getSquares() {
        var sq = (from s in n.squares
                  where s.active == true
                 orderby s.date_created descending
                 select s.html).First();
        return sq;
    }
```

My controller:

```
    public ActionResult index() {
        intranetGS.htmlDump sq = new intranetGS.htmlDump {
            html = g.getSquares()
        };

        return View(sq);
    }
```

My View:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.html)
```

All I want is for the html being passed to the view to be rendered as html and not as text.  Surely there's something different I can use in the view (instead of .DisplayFor) that will work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks very much!

Comment: For html use `@Html.Raw` answered by @neoistheone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@Html.Raw(Model.html)
```

**NOTE:** if this data can be *input* by the user - make sure it's sanitized.

Comment: I tried that, but this is what I got: Cannot convert lambda expression to type object because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Perfect - feel like I should've known that one.  Thanks!